# why query giving 0 rows

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

Query 1

```
SELECT SessionInfo.IVRSessionInfoID
FROM   SessionInfo
WHERE  SessionCallTime BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2013-08-01 00:00:00') 
                           AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2013-08-01 23:59:59')
ORDER  BY SessionInfo.SessionCallTime DESC;
```

Query 2

```
SELECT SessionInfo.IVRSessionInfoID
FROM   SessionInfo
WHERE  ( SessionInfo.SessionCallTime BETWEEN '2013-08-01 00:00:00' 
                                         AND '2013-08-01 23:59:59' )
ORDER  BY SessionInfo.SessionCallTime DESC;
```

What is the difference? Why does the first query give 0 rows and the second give records?

In this table there are 20000 rows between these two dates.

table schema

```
 CREATE TABLE `SessionInfo` (
 `IVRSessionInfoID` bigint(8) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`SessionCallTime` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`MGServerIP` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
`MGServerPort` smallint(2) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '5060',
 `SessionUniqueID` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
`ANI` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
 `CountryID` int(4) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
 `CountryStateAreaID` int(4) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
 `AccessNumberProviderLogID` int(4) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
 `AccessNumberLogID` int(4) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `AccessRestrictionLogID` int(4) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
 `SubscriberCardID` bigint(8) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `SessionDuration` int(4) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `SessionRNDDuration` int(4) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `TotalCharge` decimal(15,6) unsigned NOT NULL,
   `RuleSetLogID` int(4) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `RuleSetChargeInfoLogID` int(4) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
 `RuleSetRNDDuration` int(4) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `RuleSetTotalCharge` decimal(15,6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`IVRSessionInfoID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UNIQUE` (`SessionUniqueID`),
 KEY `SessionCallTime` (`SessionCallTime`),
 KEY `ANI` (`ANI`),
 KEY `CountryID` (`CountryID`),
KEY `CountryStateAreaID` (`CountryStateAreaID`),
  KEY `AccessNumberProviderLogID` (`AccessNumberProviderLogID`),
 KEY `AccessNumberLogID` (`AccessNumberLogID`),
KEY `AccessRestrictionLogID` (`AccessRestrictionLogID`),
 KEY `SubscriberCardID` (`SubscriberCardID`),

 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=22199955 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT;
```

Comment: the queries are different - they operate on different ranges (08-01 vs 08-31) and with different types

Comment: plz expalin where wrong here

Comment: can you post the table create statements, and some sample data, ideally as a SQLFiddle?

Comment: check updated tag...........

Answer (score 1):

[Reference](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-date-time-functions.htm#function_unix-timestamp)

If called with no argument, returns a UNIX timestamp (seconds since '1970-01-01 00:00:00' UTC) as an unsigned integer. If UNIX_TIMESTAMP() is called with a date argument, it returns the value of the argument as seconds since '1970-01-01 00:00:00' UTC. date may be a DATE string, a DATETIME string, a TIMESTAMP, or a number in the format YYMMDD or YYYYMMDD.

```
mysql> SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP();
+---------------------------------------------------------+
| UNIX_TIMESTAMP()                                        |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
| 882226357                                               |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP('1997-10-04 22:23:00');
+---------------------------------------------------------+
| UNIX_TIMESTAMP('1997-10-04 22:23:00')                   |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
| 875996580                                               |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: my que is why first query not giving results